# Page looks messy on page load, then looks fine on Refresh?

Tags: css, refresh

When I go to my website in a new tab, the navigation bar height is double the size it should be. Then, if I refresh, it looks good.
Any idea how to fix it?

My website is www.preciseos.com, when you go there, please check out the top white navigation bar and refresh. You will see the issue.

Oz

Comment: Post code. We don't click possibly malicious links for the fun of it.

Comment: for me it looks good. I use chrome latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the element `<div class="social-icons hover-big pull-right">` and more specifically from these two CSS classes :

```
.social-icons {
    display: table
}
```

and

```
.pull-right {
    float: right
}
```

In Chrome DevTools, I can replicate the bug if I disable both classes, and then apply the classes `social-icons` and `pull-right` **in this specific order**.
If you make sure that the `float: right` rule (i.e. the class `pull-right`) is applied before the `display: table` rule, it should be ok.

Comment: I have changed the order of as you mention and it solved the issue. Thank you

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Can you please mark the question as answered?

Comment: Hi Michael, how do I do that? I can't see such option.

Comment: I think you should have a check mark under the answer's vote counter. If necessary, see this post : [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score -1):

You have a problem with `jquery-1.10.2.min.map`. It has a `300` status, it isn't found on the server. Check this, and then it will be ok.

Comment: Instead of 'chit-chating', please do come with a solution. And also, please do learn what happens when a parsed js file contains an error, and how the rest of the file is influenced. P.S. See what happens in the `network` tab